# internet explorer 6/7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have recently developed a  couple of websites for a local vets and car valeter which look fine in internet explorer 9 and firefox but when viewed in internet explorer 6 or 7 it just goes wrong

In the car valeting all the boxes move down so they do not run as i have placed them (this only happens in IE6 not 7

in the vets website there is a lot of whitespace at the bottom of quite a few pages before you reach the footer.  I know IE6 and IE7 are outdated but I would still like to fix the errors if possible.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The 'errors' are probably in the *browsers*.

Comment: Please, just drop support for IE6 on your site. The three people in the world still using it must surely by now be used to every site they visit looking rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget the doctype on the top of your html file, otherwise the browser will
work in quirks mode instead of compatibility mode. Might solve your issue. Also no one uses IE 6 anymore, do not bother

check your site with the w3c validator and fix qny errors nd warnings, besides that there isnt much you can do

Answer (score -1):

A helpful approach would be to use frameworks for JavaScript (jQuery) and CSS (BluePrint) for cross browser compatibility. It will take time to migrate to new coding, but will be worth it.

On a side note, if you do not mind redirecting the users of IE 6/7 to a page suggesting they upgrade their browsers, then you may try something like this in your JS:

```
var browserVer=parseInt(navigator.appVersion); 
var browserName=navigator.appName;
if((browserName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer" && browserVer<=6) || (browserName=="Netscape" && browserVer<=3))
    window.location="Incompatible.html";
```

Where 'Incompatible' is the page where you want to redirect. Also if you use above as a function, make sure you call it:

```
   <body onLoad=yourFunction()>
```